# How does Google WiFi device speed test work?

Tags: wireless-networking, speedtest, google-wifi

I was recently using the device speed test functionality on Google Wifi (https://support.google.com/wifi/answer/7578264) and it got me wondering how this works. Ping works to arbitrary devices because they respond to ICMP, but how does a speed test to an arbitrary host work? This feature only works for devices connected via wi-fi, so presumably that is relevant?

Comment: The Google WiFi test only works for Google Mesh devices, where it's built-in.

Comment: It works for any device connected via wi-fi to a Google WiFi router.

Comment: Yes, since it's a Google device. This functionality is most likely built into the wifi chip, perhaps using the fact that wifi client devices verify continuously the router reception quality with a view to finding a better Access Path, so the router has this data. (Just a theory.)